# How can I maintain uniform thickness of bars AND switch strip position with facet_grid or facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to display data with a horizontal bar chart and facet it by a grouping variable.  Since I want a horizontal graph with faceting, I'll use `geom_barh` from the `ggstance` package.  I have a data set where my observations are divided into a few different types with counts.  Something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(observations = c(1:17), 
           type = c("a", "a", "a", "a", 
                    "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
                    "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"),
           n = c(30:46))
```

Here's my problem.  When I use `facet_wrap`, my bars have different widths:

```
library(ggstance)    

ggplot(data, aes(x = n, y = reorder(observations, n))) +
 geom_barh(stat = "identity") +
 facet_wrap(~ type, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

But when I use `facet_grid`, I can't move the strip to the top because there's no `strip.position` argument:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = n, y = reorder(observations, n))) +
 geom_barh(stat = "identity") +
 facet_grid(type ~ . , scales = "free_y", space = "free_y")
```

[image]

Is this just one of the quirks of ggplot or is there a way to manipulate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think ggplot2 is intended for this purpose, but like many other cases, if you are willing to accept a grob (rather than a ggplot2 object) as the end result, hacking a solution is possible.

The basic idea here is that `facet_wrap()` allows the strip to be in any position (top / left / right / bottom), while `fact_grid()` allows the height / width of panels to differ. If we convert the ggplot2 result from each option to a grob object, we can apply the panel heights of option 2 to option 1. Here's how:

**Step 1**. Create ggplot2 objects based on both `facet_wrap()` & `facet_grid()`. Convert them to grob objects. (note: I don't have the ggstance package installed, but the usual `geom_col()` + `coord_flip()` should be similar for the purpose of illustrating the concept here...)

```
p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(y = n, x = reorder(observations, n))) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~ type, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") +
  coord_flip()
g1 <- ggplotGrob(p1)

p2 <- ggplot(data,
       aes(y = n, x = reorder(observations, n))) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(type ~ . , scales = "free_y", space = "free_y") +
  coord_flip()
g2 <- ggplotGrob(p2)
```

**Step 2**. Get the location of panel rows in both g1 & g2's layouts:

```
g1.panel.rows <- g1$layout$t[grep("panel", g1$layout$name)] #7 / 12 / 17 in this case
g2.panel.rows <- g2$layout$t[grep("panel", g2$layout$name)] #6 / 8 / 10 in this case

# optional: view the layout & visually check that the above are correct
gtable::gtable_show_layout(g1)
gtable::gtable_show_layout(g2)

# also optional (but recommended): check the current height associated with each panel;
# note that g1 has equal height for each panel, while g2 does not    
> g1$heights[g1.panel.rows]
[1] 1null 1null 1null
> g2$heights[g2.panel.rows]
[1] 4.2null 6.2null 7.2null
```

**Step 3**. Apply g2's panel heights to g1's panels & view the result.

```
g1$heights[g1.panel.rows] <- g2$heights[g2.panel.rows]
grid::grid.draw(g1)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: That’s awesome!  I spent so much time trying to hack this with `vjust`, `hjust`, and `margin` arguments to no avail.  Is there anywhere I can read more about `grob`s so I can understand what’s going on behind the scenes? I spent a lot of time on the ggplot GitHub page and was more confused when I left.