# ggplot2: Varying facet width with independent `Y` axes

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, gridview, graph

**Dummy data**

```
d = data.frame(
    x = factor(LETTERS[c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)]),
    y = c(100,80,70,60,130,90,65,60,2,3,3,3,2,2,1,2),
    grid = rep(letters[1:2], each=8)
)
```

**Issue**

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y)) + facet_grid(~grid, scales="free",space="free_x") + geom_point()
```

[image]

I like this graph. My only issue is that both grids use the same `Y` axis. So, I tried using `facet_wrap` instead of `facet_grid` and got

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y)) + facet_wrap(~grid, scales="free") + geom_point()
```

[image]

But unfortunately, `facet_wrap` does not have a "space" parameter and as a result the right and the left graph are of the same width.

**Question**

How can I do so that the space between levels of the variable `d$x` is equal among both facets (leading to facets having different width) AND to have a separate `Y` axis for each facet. Of course, I would like to keep the facets to be aligned horizontally.

Comment: Don't know a way to do this currently, but you can give a thumbs-up to [this issue on github](https://github.com/thomasp85/ggforce/issues/114)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ggplot grob and modify the widths in the table

```
# Capture the plot
q = ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y)) + facet_grid(~grid, scales="free",space="free_x") + geom_point()
gt = ggplotGrob(q)

# Modify the widths
gt$widths[5] = unit(8, "cm")
gt$widths[9] = unit(4, "cm")

# Plot the graph
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

Comment: For a less manual way to specify facet widths, you can take reference from the `facet_grid` version of the plot & apply the relative widths to the `facet_wrap` version. I've previously done something similar for facet heights [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51907493/8449629) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55224846/8449629).